# How to run supabase functions in the admin API?

Tags: reactjs, supabase

I have been using Supabase for a couple months and I really like what I see. User authentication is pretty simple. I have sign up with email verification, sign in, and password reset all working. My question is how to invite a user thoriugh email? There is a function called inviteUserByEmail(), however, it is part of the admin API.

https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/supabase-auth-admin-api says anything that starts with supabase.auth.admin must be called on a trusted server. I don't understand what it means by server. I thought supabase provided what I need? Can anybody offer me an explaination?

I have looked all over the internet and youtube and there are no examples of this anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Admin requests are meant to be used server side.
https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/admin-api

You could try having the same user experience by using the auth signup request https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-signup